# jQuery Math Equation (slight return)

Tags: jquery, math

I need a little help adjusting this code, any advice is appreciated:

The desired result is to have two values returned instead of just one, so for example:

```
Input Value = " " (Text box )
this.value = 226 - this.value * .5;  ( value #1 Text Box2) 
this.value = 226 - this.value * .9;  ( value #2 Text Box3)
```

HTML

```
<form id='myform'>
    <input value=" "/><br>
    <a href="#" class='THR'>click to calculate THR</a><br><br>
</form>
```

CODE

```
$('a.THR').click(function() {
    $('#myform :text').each(function() {
    this.value = 226 - this.value * .5;
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where do you want the second value? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Any better? Essentially three boxes, one for the input value and two for the return values

Comment: Where are the boxes for the return values?

Comment: From what I gather: You have a text box the user can enter numbers into. When the user clicks the link (submitting the form would be more semantic), you want to display two numbers based on the entered value in the text box. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not really sure what you want to accomplish but if you just want to make two calculations and display the results you can do this:

HTML:

```
<input id="number" value="" /><br>
<a href="#" class='THR'>click to calculate THR</a>
<div id="answer1"></div>
<div id="answer2"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('a.THR').click(function() {
    var value = parseInt( $( "#number" ).val() );
    $( "#answer1" ).html( 226 - value * 0.5 );
    $( "#answer2" ).html( 226 - value * 0.9 );
    return false;
});
```

Since you have only one input field there's no reason to use an each loop, just give it an id and refer to it directly. The containers for the results can be anything you want as long as you can refer to them with jQuery (ids are a good choice).

Comment: Juhana, that is exactly what I was getting at, thanks very much for your help